# Generating confusing list of random numbers that user must sort ASC/DESC

Tags: java, algorithm, random, numbers, statistics

### Background

I and a few others are developing an android Alarm application in a project at our university.
We have a concept called "Challenges" in which the user must complete one in order to shut the alarm of. One of these challenges / user stories are to sort a list of numbers ASC/DESC correctly.

### Problem

The goal/problem is to offer the user a list that provides the maximum confusion, so that the list is as hard as possible to sort for a human.

My basic idea is that if you get a list of shuffled numbers, e.g: [131, 129, 315, 328, 931, 953], that would be hard to sort (if you have a better idea of confusion, please share).

Computing performance is not our main concern here, rather the quality of the list is.

### An attempt at solving

First I immediately searched for Fisher-Yates, shuffling, and then went on to look for information about variance and standard deviation.

One of my friends suggested that if we say (step 1) generate 3 numbers from say 100-999, and then (step2) generate 3 smaller numbers (say 1- for each of the big ones and add to the big ones we get a nice and confusing list of numbers. And maybe throw in some checks to make sure the bigger numbers are varied enough, and that the smaller ones are not too varied. And at the end, we do a shuffling of the computed numbers.

The best I came up with (written in Java, but any language is fine) was:

```
    // Config variables.
    int min = 101;
    int max = 999;
    int innerMin = 1;
    int innerMax = 99;

    int innerSize = 3;
    int outerSize = 3;

    // The numbers here were just picked "at random".
    double minVariance = 100.0;
    double maxInnerVariance = 33.0;

    // java.util.Random is maybe not optimal, but for now...
    Random rng = new Random();

    int[] numbers = new int[outerSize * innerSize];

    // Fill big array first.
    int[] big = new int[outerSize];
    while ( computeVariance( big ) < minVariance ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < outerSize; ++i ) {
            int random;
            do {
                // Maybe use nextGaussian here instead?
                random = (int) (min + (rng.nextDouble() * (max - min)));
            } while ( random % 10 == 0 ); // Exclude all numbers that are modulo 10, too easy.

            big[i] = random;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < outerSize; ++i ) {
        // Fill a small array for each big array.
        int[] small = new int[innerSize];
        while ( computeVariance( small ) > maxInnerVariance ) {
            for ( int j = 0; i < innerSize; ++i ) {
                int random;
                do {
                    // Maybe use nextGaussian here instead?
                    random = (int) (innerMin + (rng.nextDouble() * (innerMax - innerMin)));
                } while ( random % 10 == 0 ); // Exclude all numbers that are modulo 10, too easy.

                small[i] = big[i] + random;
                numbers[innerSize * i + j] = small[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally shuffle.
    fisherYatesShuffle( numbers, rng );
```

As you can see, the code seems quite complex, 4 nested loops - ouch? Is there a better was to do this conceptually, or algorithmically, etc.?

### Edits

Edit 1, made some assumptions clearer after @ElKamina :s comment...

I have made the following visual assumptions:
- the list of numbers are visually shuffled.
- they are shuffled again to provide background colors to the numbers in order to give extra confusion.
- to combat the problem you raised with cognition, the numbers are represented in a grid so that doesn't apply.

Now a model assumption:
 - all numbers have 3 digits (they don't differ in length).

### Working Solution

Redid the entire implementation and got it to work using nextGaussian, etc. This solution guarantees uniqueness in every cluster (AFAIK) and may be slowish but it is robust and quality > speed here (optimizations to the code are more than welcome).

Using 2.0 standard deviations gives a good and nice spread as I feel.
More code @ http://pastebin.com/iu3U6VG0

```
    @Override
    public int[] generateList( Random rng, int size ) {
        // outer = index 0, inner = index 1.
        int[] sizes = computeSizes( size );
        int[] numbers = new int[sizes[0] * sizes[1]];
        int outerMultiplier = com.google.common.math.IntMath.pow( 10, this.numDigits - 1 );
        int innerMax = outerMultiplier - 1;

        // Fill outer array first.
        int[] outer = new int[sizes[0]];
        for ( int i = 0; i < sizes[0]; ++i ) {
            outer[i] = RandomMath.nextRandomRanged( rng, 1, 9 ) * outerMultiplier;
        }

        // Fill inner array for each outer array.
        for ( int i = 0; i < sizes[0]; ++i ) {
            // Calculate bounds [min, max].
            int[] innerBounds = new int[] { RandomMath.nextRandomNon10( rng, 1, innerMax ), RandomMath.nextRandomNon10( rng, 1, innerMax ) };
            int diff = innerBounds[1] - innerBounds[0];
            if ( diff < 0 ) {
                // Wrong order, swap!
                PrimitiveArrays.swap( innerBounds, 0, 1 );
                diff = -diff;
            }
            if ( diff < sizes[1] ) {
                // Difference is too small, make sure we got room!
                innerBounds[0] = Math.max( 1, innerBounds[0] - sizes[1] );
                innerBounds[1] = innerBounds[0] + sizes[1];

                diff = innerBounds[1] - innerBounds[0];
            }

            BitSet bits = new BitSet( diff );
            boolean filledModulo10 = false;

            // Now do the filling.
            int[] inner = new int[sizes[1]];
            for ( int j = 0; j < sizes[1]; ++j ) {
                inner[j] = RandomMath.nextGaussianNon10( rng, innerBounds[0], innerBounds[1], MAX_GAUSS_ITERATIONS, INNER_STANDARD_DEVIATIONS );

                // Protect against same numbers all the time, can we do away with this loop? not O(n) but still...
                boolean hasDuplicate = false;
                for ( int k = 0; k < j; ++k ) {
                    if ( inner[k] == inner[j] ) {
                        hasDuplicate = true;
                    }
                }

                if ( hasDuplicate ) {
                    if ( !filledModulo10 ) {
                        // Set all numbers that end with 0 in BitSet, we don't want them!
                        // This assumes that neither innerBounds[0, 1] are modulo 10.
                        for ( int l = ((innerBounds[0] / 10) + 1) * 10; l <= innerBounds[1]; l += 10 ) {
                            bits.set( l - innerBounds[0] );
                        }

                        filledModulo10 = true;
                    }

                    // Find first false bit.
                    // This beats the idea of randomness, but avoiding duplicates is more important!
                    inner[j] = bits.nextClearBit( 0 ) + innerBounds[0];
                }

                bits.set( inner[j] - innerBounds[0] );

                numbers[sizes[1] * i + j] = outer[i] + inner[j];
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }
```

Comment: TL,DR: Create a list of random numbers that contains smaller clusters of nearby numbers?

Comment: Yeah, good TL:DR; One constraint I forgot to mention is that the smaller clusters (assuming that all numbers have 3 digits, but don't assume that in code) of nearby numbers must have the same most-significant digit, so e.g: [107, 111, 118], [342, 346, 351], [981, 984, 986] is good.

Comment: The code I provided does unfortunately not honor this. Maybe I'm going about this entirely the wrong way - what  if we just generate the most outer number first like so: rand([1-9]) * 100 and then add lower numbers to this generated with nextGaussian with a randomized mean and & a stdDev randomized from a low interval? How fast is nextGaussian performance wise (not really an issue, but still...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a working solution @ http://pastebin.com/iu3U6VG0 - or read the question =)

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is very poorly defined. When you ask humans to sort, I think the most difficult part is to understand how "big" or "small" a number is (the visual cognition is more important) .

Example: Visually if you provide numbers in the same line, it is difficult to sort them. You have to count how many digits they have etc.

It is easier to sort:

```
111111
99999
```

as compared to

```
111111, 99999
```

So, hardness of sorting for humans is very subjective and unless you put some constraints, this is a ill defined problem.

**Reply to OP's Edit**

You haven't still mentioned what "hardware" can humans use. Do they have a grid based computer interface where they can move around the numbers with a mice? Or, the numbers are printed over a paper and you need to "output" those numbers on another sheet of paper in written form?

You can start with a problem that is actually a real problem. Assume you have a bunch of baseball cards with some stats on it (say total runs). And you want to sort your cards according to that stat. Can we start from here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Edited my post outlining some assumptions / constraints made.

With those constraints put, I (very subjectively) believe that sorting numbers with a high variation coefficient as a whole but low in the smaller clusters is difficult, at least it is for me.

Comment: Actually, I did mention the GUI, it's a android phone or tablet, touch screen capability is assumed. =)

Comment: @Centril Sorry, I missed that. How exactly does the interface work? Can you drag and drop numbers around? What are the relative difficulties for each operation?

Comment: Assume a grid of equals in a square. You tap buttons.